# Render component on certain paths only react router v6

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

How can I only render the breadcrumbheader component on homepage and version page? I don't want it to display on the not found page. I am using outer route with outlet because I need to access to useLocation hook in breadcrumb header and this is the only way to achieve that.

```
<div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route
          element={
            <>
              <Header />
              <BreadcrumbHeader />
              <Outlet />
            </>
          }
        >
          <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
          <Route path="/version/:Id" element={<VersionPage />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundPage />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another layout component to wrap the `HomePage` and `VersionPage` components so they are rendered with the `BreadcrumbHeader`.

```
<div className="App">
  <Routes>
    <Route
      element={(
        <>
          <Header />
          <Outlet />
        </>
      )}
    >
      <Route
        element={(
          <>
            <BreadcrumbHeader />
            <Outlet />
          </>
        )}
      >
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/version/:Id" element={<VersionPage />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundPage />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay so why couldn't I think of this myself duh. Someone give this man a raise! Always coming to the rescue.

Answer (score 1):

2 ways :

- useLocation and compare the location.path on your BreadCrumb component, something like =>

  const location = useLocation()
  render(
  <>
  {location.path === 'toto' && }
  </>
  )

If you have just 2 or 3 routes, it's "ok", if you want more...

- nested routes !!  much better practice =>

  <Route path="/" element={}>
  <Route path="/version/:id" element={} />
  // other routes with breadC

You create a component ContainerWithBreath, you put the component BreadC here, don't forget to use  (see the doc, it's like says "put the nested component here").

see doc part "nesting routes" for more explain

// Edit
So in fact, nesting routes is a route with subRoutes, for example :
/user is routes
/user/profil is subRoutes

So for that, you use Route component that take path='/user' and render a component like container with your component similar for each of subRoutes.
Children of this route, you put new component route, with the sub page.

In your case

```
<Route path="/" element={<ContainerWithB />} >
<Route path="/version/:Id" element={<VersionPage />} />
<Route index element={<Home />} />
</Route>
```

First line render container (you need to place  on the render of ContainerWithB to display the nested route element .
Second line your VersionPage
Third line your Home page for '/'

Better ?

Comment: Can you explain the second method a bit further, please? Not sure I understand. Just to be clear I want the breadcrumbheader to be displayed on the home and version paths but not on the not found page which is basically any other path. And I still want to render it with the outlet as a parent route because I need access to useLocation in Breadcrumbheader.

Comment: Yes I understand now. Thank you friend.

Answer (score 0):

For react-router 6 you can use `<Outlet />` tag

[More info](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/outlet)